# Usage of elements from different tables

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I have these tables:

```
Member(MID, Name, Surname, DateOfBirth)
Library(LID, Name, YearOfOpenning)
Book(ISBN, LID, Name)
Renting(RID, MID, ISBN, From, Until)
```

I need to find oldest member of the library that rented at least 1 book from oldest library.

Finding oldest member is easy, but when I need to combine with oldest library, here comes the problems.

```
select *
from member
where member.DATEOFBIRTH = (
select min (member.dateofbirth)
from member)
```

Also, I need to find out all libraries from where the books has been rented by the member that has most renting on his account.
I tried these 2 questions for 3 hours, and still I got almost nowhere.

So far, I managed to find the one who has most renting, but I dont know how to write a code where only library will be displayed, according to the entries I already made for the member that has most renting (instead of breaking it into pieces).

```
select renting.mid, count(renting.mid) as total
from renting
where renting.mid in (
select member.mid
from member
where renting.mid = member.mid)
group by mid
order by count(renting.mid) desc;
select * 
from library
where library.lid in (
select renting.lid
from renting
where renting.mid = 3);
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: This looks like homeword. What have you tried?

Comment: It is actually homework from few years back, but I'm using it for practice. For 1st question, I was able to find oldest member that rented at any library (SELECT * FROM member WHERE member.dateofbirth = (
SELECT MIN(member.dateofbirth) FROM member WHERE member.mid IN ( SELECT renting.mid FROM renting))

Could not figure out a way to find out the oldest library.

Comment: Don't put your tries in comment. Add it as part of your question. Your question should be: `'I want do A but Im getting B, what is wrong'`. But right now your question is `'do this for me'` and we aren't a free code service. Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

Comment: Is the dangerously named "From" column, LID?

Answer (score 0):

You should get the oldest one  that rent a book (the member must join with renting)

```
  SELECT * FROM member 
  WHERE member.dateofbirth = 
  ( SELECT MIN(member.dateofbirth) 
      FROM member 
      INNER JOIN renting on member.mid = renting.mid)
```

and this should manage also the oldest libary

```
  SELECT * FROM member 
  WHERE member.dateofbirth = 
  ( SELECT MIN(member.dateofbirth) 
      FROM member 
      INNER JOIN renting on member.mid = renting.mid
      INNER JOIN Book on Book.ISBN = renting.ISBN
      INNER JOIN Library on Library.LID = Book.LID
      where rownum = 1
      ORDER BY Library.YearOfOpening )
```

Comment: You miss the `oldest library` part

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza    i don't see any relation in tables  that can lead to this concept .. so .. i  hope that the OP explain better this part .... w

Comment: `YearOfOpenning` told you which is the oldest library. But You are right not sure if books have a link to library

Comment: OK  . for YearOfOpenning   but what i don't see is how the table libary is related  to the others

Comment: answer  updated .. hoping that the relation between library and book is based on name

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake inside the Book table. Instead of BID it should have been LID. It is helpful, but not the kind of what I've been looking for precisely. I've arrived on same result different path, but couldn't figure out how to select oldest library afterwards.

Comment: answer  updated with LID instead of name  ..  so the order by YearOfOpening ASC and limt should return the  resul related  to oldest libray too . )  hope this is what you are looking for

Comment: @scaisEdge I did some editing on the post today, as I found myself busy yesterday. Thanks for your help, but it seems like this aint working for me. I'm also using oracle sql, not the one from Microsoft, so, as u know, limit is not included in oracle, and yet, it is displaying me error right after you selected oldest member (on the INNER JOIN field - invalid relational operator)
Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Guev4ra   answer  updated  for oracle  (oracle don't use limt but rownum filter)

Comment: @scaisEdge right after "where member.mid", on the INNER JOIN renting... part of the code it shows me an error :(